# what's wrong to split text by newline code

Tags: bash

What's wrong with below code to split text block by newline?

```
#!/bin/bash
txt="abcd
efg hijk lmn
opq
rst"

lines=${txt%$'\n'*}
for line in $lines; do
    echo $line
done
```

Current output is:

```
abcd
efg
hijk
lmn
opq
```

expected output:

```
abcd
efg hijk lmn
opq
rst
```

Comment: Use `mapfile -t arr <<< "$txt"` and then iterate the array.

Comment: `for line in $lines` splits on `IFS`, which by default means whitespace. The easy fix would be to not assign the variable separately; `( IFS=$'\n';  for line in $txt; do echo "$line"; done )` where the parentheses create a subshell to ensure that the change to `IFS` is not persisted. But probably a better solution is to put the lines in an array, as suggested by @anubhava - or just `echo "$txt"` if all you want is to echo the lines, of course.

Comment: @tripleee Great, but some bash (android) do not support " parentheses create a subshell ", any other way for such shell?

Comment: Every remotely POSIX-compliant shell can fork itself. It's definitely not Bash if it lacks that functionality; it could not run other programs either if it wasn't able to run itself. A crude workaround is to save the original value of IFS and then restore it; `oldIFS=$IFS; for line in $txt; do echo "$line"; done; IFS=$oldIFS`